# Inline merge conflict resolver in PyCharm/IntelliJ/JetBrains IDEs

Tags: git, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

Switched back again to PyCharm recently. **VS Code** has this handy inline merge conflict resolver which you could select the action you want, and for trickier conflicts, you could move the line up/down, update the codes, etc and after that you could click the action you want:
[image]

And **Atom** has similar feature:
[image]

But it seems there's no equivalent feature/plugin in PyCharm or other IntelliJ-based IDEs? In PyCharm, need to summon a new window to resolve the conflicts. Tried also the [**Git Conflict**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10656-git-conflict) and [**GitToolBox**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) plugins, but still no similar feature. Am I missing something? Shouldn't JetBrains consider this feature?

Comment: PyCharm and other jetBrains products have a conflict resolve UI that helps you do a lot of stuff including what you described, idk if you checked this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/resolve-conflicts.html), maybe you'll see what you're looking for, sorry i haven't used VS code or atom in years so idk exactly how the UI works in comparison

Comment: Yup, I've tried that also, but it's annoying since you need to open a new window, besides the main editor editor. As per my questions above:
"In PyCharm, need to summon a new window to resolve the conflicts."

In VS Code/Atom, you don't need to open a new window and could edit directly the conflicted file in the main editor window using the inline resolver buttons. In PyCharm, technically you could inline edit also those by manually removing the Git conflict markers, but there's no handy buttons like in VS Code/Atom, as per my screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no option to enable inline conflict resolution, but there is a feature request for it, please feel free to vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140959

Comment: This is close to what I want, probably will either upvote it or create a new feature request that's more clear w/ VS Code/Atom screenshots. Thanks

Comment: Submitted a new Feature Request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJSDK-928

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ does support conflict resolution. It has the feature you are looking for (and maybe more).

Once you are in a state of merge (or just a conflict), navigate `VCS` > `Git` > `Resolve Conflicts`. A window will pop open, where you can immediately decide to either accept "Yours" or "Theirs" changes, or if you want a fine-grain approach, click the <kbd>Merge</kbd> button.

That will open a window like so:

[image]

The left and right arrow buttons / ex-es will either accept theirs/yours changes to the merging file in the middle. This whole configuration can be made different, the panels can be changed, there are other buttons to merge the whole "ours/theirs" changes, hotkeys for some actions, and many other features.

The IntelliJ [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-conflicts.html#distributed-version-control-systems) talks about it in detail.

Comment: Yup, I know this. But this opens a new window. My question is about the conflict resolution inline with the main editor (i.e. without opening a new window) which VS Code/Atom supports.

Comment: Hm, I don't think you can inline that window to be put into the main Idea window space.